# Best way to parse a list of numbers

Tags: java, c++, regex, parsing, text-processing

I have a problem in that I need to process a list of numbers, which will be in an English sentence.  It could be in the following formats:

items 1, 2 and 3

items 2 through 5

items 1 to 20

items 4 or 8

My initial instinct is to write a simple state machine to parse it, but I was wondering if there is any better (simpler) way, such as maybe some regular expression.  Any advice?

Comment: Btw, a regular expression is a representation of a state machine :)

Comment: Is there a difference between `2 and 3` and `2 or 3`?

Comment: no difference, they are supposed to use "or" but sometimes they use "and".

Comment: bah, I made a C++ answer, but it fails if there's no spaces after seperators, so "1,2,3" would fail.

Comment: I don't think there will generally be any list items without spaces between.

Comment: What is the difference between `1, 2` `1 or 2` and `1 and 2`

Comment: no difference, just a difference in the way the user entered the input.  They all come down to just a list of two numbers 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++11, the following parser (AXE) will parse all your formats (I didn't test it):

```
unsigned i;
auto num = axe::r_unsigned(i);
auto space = axe::r_any(" \t");
auto format1 = num % (*space & ',' & *space) & ~("and" & +space & num);
auto format2 = num & +space & "through" & +space & num;
auto format3 = num & +space & "to" & +space & num;
auto format4 = num & +space & "or" & +space & num;
auto format = "items" & +space & (format1 | format2 | format3 | format4);
```

If you don't have C++11, you can write a similar parser in C++ using *boost::spirit*. It's easier and shorter to write and debug such parser than using regular expressions, and you also get a lot of flexibility in creating parsing rules and semantic actions.

Comment: wow, I need to learn C++11, that looks completely foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wedded to Java, use the Regular Expression functionality.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

But if you're not, a sed script works best for simple text processing.

```
sed 's/\d{1,} /\1 /g' < file.txt
```

Comment: You can use regexes also in C++, they are included into the new revision of the language (C++11) and they are available as a separate library (e.g. Boost.Regex) for the previous one. On the other hand, in C++ I'd probably just write a small parser, it wouldn't be difficult at all.

Comment: Regex library was actually introduced a few years ago in TR1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very simple to write a parser for those strings using a regular expression for each case, or a single expression with an alternative for each. You need to use something like  `\d+` to match the numbers. I would also group each set of similar combinators (like 
"and"/"or" and "to"/"through") into a single alternative to make it easier to process the results.